# How to truncate zeroes from an account number

Tags: formula, formula-field

I have a system which originally got account numbers from legacy system whose account numbers used zeros as a prefix. When the account numbers were brought into Salesforce the zeros were trimmed off and they do not exist in the Salesforce account ID.

Now we are being forced to refer to the old system for various reasons. So I need to figure out a way to match the current Salesforce account IDs with the original ones with the zeros.

If it were a matter of adding a specific amount of zeroes to the prefix of the Salesforce account IDs I wouldn't be sweating it. But some of the old accounts filled their zeros. So I have account numbers of an inconsistent type such as :

```
61260012418
60008030650
60015107804
```

Essentially, **I want to trim the leading `6` and all of the zeros which immediately follow it**. So my final numbers should be as such :

```
126001241
8030650
15107804
```

What would be the best approach for this ? If I could figure out a field formula to trim them then I could just import the entire IDs into Salesforce and trim off everything from the final 0 to the left. Does anybody know of any logic which could do that ?

If you knew of an Excel formula which could do it before I import it into Salesforce that would work too.

Comment: 61260012418 for this what should be the output?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here it is, most simple way to achieve this

```
IF(
   BEGINS(Customer_Account_No__c, "6"),  
   TEXT(VALUE(RIGHT(Customer_Account_No__c, LEN(Customer_Account_No__c)-1))), 
  "")
```

> Converting Text to `Value()` function trims off leading zeros. This is the trick!!!

Or, with the use of `MID` rather than `RIGHT`  function

```
IF(
   BEGINS(Customer_Account_No__c, "6"),  
   TEXT(VALUE(MID(Customer_Account_No__c, 2, LEN(Customer_Account_No__c)-1))), 
   "")
```

Comment: I think MID might still be a bit more efficient but that's certainly a huge improvement on my approach!

Comment: Yes, I can change RIGHT to MID

Comment: I'm glad my way was not the best one. That would not have been very scalable.

Comment: Actually, I am learning from you

Comment: Well sounds like SFSE is doing its job if we're all learning from each other. :)

Answer (score 5):

Here's one brutally inefficient solution which ought to at least work:

```
IF(
    BEGINS(AccountNumber, '60000'),
    MID(AccountNumber, 6, LEN(AccountNumber)),
    IF(
        BEGINS(AccountNumber, '6000'),
        MID(AccountNumber, 5, LEN(AccountNumber)),
        IF(
            BEGINS(AccountNumber, '600'),
            MID(AccountNumber, 4, LEN(AccountNumber)),
            IF(
                BEGINS(AccountNumber, '60'),
                MID(AccountNumber, 3, LEN(AccountNumber)),
                IF(
                    BEGINS(AccountNumber, '6'),
                    MID(AccountNumber, 2, LEN(AccountNumber)),
                    AccountNumber
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

It'd probably be better to just make it a writeable field and use `Apex` or workflows. But if you want a formula, this one should do the trick. It should be obvious how to expand it to account for more leading zeroes if necessary.

Demonstration of the results:

[image: Query Results]

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that all of your accounts are 11 digits and all of them start with 6, the simplest solution is :

```
TEXT(VALUE(Customer_Account_No__c)-60000000000)
```